Form action / server action causes fetch in SSR page to re-trigger
Im trying to understand an issue we're encountering in our Next.js app v.14 (app router).
We have an SSR page that first validates a JWT token by calling a verify-token endpoint. If the token is valid, we render a form (use-client directive) on this page. The form uses a client-side action to validate the user input. After successful validation, it triggers a server-side action, which communicates with an API to register the user.
The issue we're seeing is that after a successful form submission, verifySignupToken is called again. Since we're doing client-side navigation after the form submission with router.push, we should jump straight to the new route? I'm not sure why it re-triggers the fetch call again in the parent component?
SSR page (with force-dynamic config opt):
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default async function Signup({ searchParams }: SignUpProps) {
  const { token, customerId, email } = searchParams

  const result = safeParse(VerifySignupSchema, { token, email, customerId })

  if (!result.success) {
    console.error(result.issues)
    redirect('/login?error=validation')
  }

  const validatedData = result.output

  try {
    await verifySignupToken(validatedData.token, validatedData.customerId, validatedData.email)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      redirect(`/login?error=${encodeURIComponent(error.message)}`)
    }
  }

  return (
    <SignUpForm
      token={validatedData.token}
      customerId={validatedData.customerId}
      email={validatedData.email}
    />
  )
}

SignUpForm (use-client directive with a client side action calling a server side action):
export const SignUpForm = ({ token, customerId, email }: SignUpFormProps) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()

  const signUpClientAction = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const password = formData.get('password')
    const pnr = formData.get('pnr')

    const result = safeParse(SignUpSchema, { password, pnr })

    if (!result.success) {
      toast.error(result.issues[0].message)
      return
    }

    const validatedData = result.output

    const response = await signupAction(
      email,
      validatedData.password,
      token,
      validatedData.pnr,
      customerId
    )

    if (response.success) {
      toast.success(response.message)
      router.push('/')
    } else if (response.statusCode === 401) {
      toast.error(response.message)
      router.push('/login')
    } else {
      toast.error(response.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <div>
        <form className="space-y-6" action={signUpClientAction}>
    ....




Can you provide a repo with minimum reproduction code?

Before next.js 13 next.js had shallow routing which is a technique that allows you to update the URL of a page without reloading the page itself or fetching new data from the server.
From shallow-routing-with-next-js-v13-app-directory-

In Next.js v13, adding or removing search parameters invariably
triggers a hard-reload. In contrast, Next.js v12 allowed for a command
like router.push('/?counter=10', undefined, { shallow: true }) to be
executed without initiating a hard reload. Unfortunately, in the
current version, similar code always results in a hard-reload, causing
all components to re-render, even though it’s the same page.
Solution


When faced with such limitations in newly implemented applications, it’s always a good idea to revisit the web APIs. Our
goal here is to find a way to modify the URL instantly without
triggering a full page reload.
A popular method to achieve this is by using
“window.history.pushState()”.
now I needed to listen to the changes in the URL from another
components. So let’s write a hook to do that for us.

import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const usePushStateListener = (callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     // make a copy of original function to avoid complications
    const originalPushState = history.pushState;

    history.pushState = function (data, title, url) {
      originalPushState.apply(history, [data, title, url]);
      callback(url); 

    return () => {
      history.pushState = originalPushState; // restore the copy
    };
  }, [callback]);
};


When the “window.history.pushState” method is called in any
components, the overridden “pushState” method defined in the
“usePushStateListener” hook will be executed. This allows the hook to
listen the URL changes and trigger callback function with the updated
URL.

